# Controlling the flow of app schemes.

Tags: android, ios

The company I work with develop a clothes website with two associated apps. One for general clothes-purchasing use, and the other specifically for women's shoes. There are iOS and Android versions of both apps.

We currently have a custom scheme for both apps: `mycompany://` and `mycompanyladyshoes://`. I want to know if there is a way to, after the user clicks on a link with `mycompanyladyshoes://...`, and doesn't have the ladies' shoes app installed then redirect to the original app, and *then* if that app isn't installed redirect to the Play/iTunes store.

Is there any way to control where the links direct to if certain apps are or aren't installed?

Answer (score 0):

(This is for Android, I have no idea what iOS uses for this kind of functionality)

What you want to do is add an `<intent-filter>` to an activity in the receiving app that accepts the custom scheme.

```
<activity ... >
    <intent-filter>
        <action name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <data android:scheme="mycompanyladyshoes" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

To launch the play store if it's not installed, you could first check that the device has an app installed that can open the implicit intent:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setData(Uri.parse("mycompanyladyshoes://");

// check if it can be handled
PackageManager pm = context.getPackageManager();
List<ResolveInfo> activities = pm.queryIntentActivities(intent);
if (activities != null && activities.size() > 0) {
    // an installed app can resolve this intent
    startActivity(intent);
} else {
    // no installed app can resolve it; open play store instead
    intent.setData(Uri.parse("market://details?id=" + appPackageName));
    startActivity(intent);
}
```